# Deploy war inside project folder

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, war

I have a project called myapp (webapps/myapp)
Now I want to deploy a sample.war inside myapp.
What I need to do?
If I have to write a context.xml inside META-INF. What will be the content of context.xml?
Do I need server.xml? If yes, What will be the content of context.xml?

Comment: what ide are you using?

Comment: Without ide :-P
I can use ide like eclipse or intelJ but I want to do it manually.
for knowledge purpose only